# VBS - Machine Name into part of olink.targetpath

Tags: vbscript

So, here is what I am trying to do. We are rolling out a basic timekeeping solution for staff to clock in and out via a Liquid Office form. To simplify things, I want to automatically create shortcuts. I've managed to pass the IP of the machine, now I need to pass the name of the machine into the first part of the URL.

Can this be done? I need to replace the "MACHINENAME" with the actual machine name, dim-ed as CompName.

```
'This script will grab the local active netowork adapter IP, host name, and  and creates the time keeping shortcut, using the machines IP address. 
'This script will take the local machine name and ammed it to the URL for the cash registers. 

dim NIC1, Nic, StrIP, CompName

Set NIC1 = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

For Each Nic in NIC1

    if Nic.IPEnabled then

        StrIP = Nic.IPAddress(i)

        Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

        CompName= WshNetwork.Computername

        Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        sLinkFile = "C:\Users\public\desktop\Clock in & Out.LNK"
        Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
        oLink.TargetPath = "http://MACHINENAME:8080/lfserver/timecard?ip_address=" &StrIP
        oLink.Description = "Clock in or out"   
        oLink.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll, 111"
        oLink.Save

        wscript.quit

    end if

next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after. Adding the computer name to the http path?

```
 oLink.TargetPath = "http://" & CompName & ":8080/lfserver/timecard?ip_address=" & StrIP
```

Comment: YEP! Thanks! That would be it. I wasn't adding the 2nd & sign. So it was goofing up on me. I knew there had to be a way, just couldn't figure out how!